# login credentials of 14.04 LTS

Tags: login, password

I am running ubuntu 14.04 lts from a dvd.I am prompted to enter login and password.I tried ubuntu.guest etc.., but of no use
 Please guide me how to proceed.
Regards,
Dr Srikanth
918801245435

Comment: I've had this problem in virtualbox. Not sure how to proceed. On a regular computer, you can sometimes set a password using ctrl + alt + F2 and (hopefully) it won't ask for a sign in and if you can execute commands, execute `sudo passwd ubuntu` or `sudo passwd ubuntu-live` or whatever the user name is listed as. If the user name is ubuntu it will say ubuntu@ubuntu if it is ubuntu-live it should say ubuntu-live@ubuntu and if ubuntu-trusty: ubuntu-trusty@ubuntu etc. You will be prompted to set a password so make someting up and use that password you set to sign into what ever username it was set

Comment: As stated below you shouldn't be asked for a password unless you sign out and then try to sign back in. If you want to do that, you need to set a password using the passwd command before you sign out.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have an incomplete download of the .iso or the burn went wrong.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes - This page contains all of the md5 hashes for the different versions of Ubuntu. Just look for the version you downloaded and see what the hash should be

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM - Page shows how to check the iso using different operating systems. If the hash matches up, there is no problem with the iso file so that means something went wrong with the burn.

If you don't want to go through the trouble of checking, just download again (I would suggest using torrent) and make sure it finishes. Then burn at the slowest speed possible. Or if you have a usb drive and a bios that supports, just use that instead.

Edit: I forgot to mention. The reason I say this is you should not be prompted to log in.